# How do I set the KDE panel to be a long continuous one across dual monitors?

Tags: kde

I'm using KDE with two monitors, and I'd like to set the panel on the desktop to be a long continuous panel along the bottom of both monitors, instead of the two separated panels. How could I do that? :)

I hope you understand what I want. :D

Answer (score 0):

It's currently not possible. Apparently, it's a design decision of the KDE team.